# Can php block all ips except for the state of hawaii from seeing something?

Tags: php, ip

I'm trying to show specific services on my site for only those living in the state of Hawaii and show other services for those outside of it. Is there an easy way of doing this in PHP? I'm not restricting full access, so it cant be an htaccess thing and I don't want it to be javascript or jquery.

Comment: [Geolocation](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=geolocation) and a bit of elbow grease.

Comment: If you have some api for resolving ip locations you can use `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`